# Samsung mystyle m340s keeps restarting

Tags: reboot, samsung

Device: Samsung mystyle m340s

My phone is made in Korea. The Korean software keeps restarting from boot screen.

I tried factory reset from Android system recovery, but it didn't help. The local Samsung Service Center says they do not have foreign software for it. So, they cant re-install Android.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Where are you at? USA?

Comment: no i am at india

Comment: isn't here any one who can solve my problem??

Comment: Do you really need Korean software? What if you ask the Service Center to flash your phone with an Indian ROM?

Comment: they told me it will not support & it will end with bricking ... I dont have much knowledge about it... but as i searched in net korean version doesn't support international version.. but is it possible to flash it with international ROM ??